# Handle In App Purchases

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, skproduct

I have been researching, and I apologize if this is a duplicate, but I haven't found anything in regards;

I am curious on how to handle pricing, in regards to retrieving from

`func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse)`

Should  we be calling this method EVERY TIME the app is opened, retrieving the information from apple? Or should we save to UserDefaults and retrieve from there every time?

Also, what is the most appropriate way to handle the user being offline?

Answer (score 0):

The products should be requested ahead of displaying the products to the user (depending on the use case of you app, this could very well be on launch). Do not save them in User Defaults because if they are hard-coded but become unavailable or the price changes, there will be discrepancies with the data displayed and what can be purchased.

When a user is offline, they cannot purchase the items anyways. Users should be able to view the products available to them at the given moment (which are the products returned in the productsRequest)